# If $f$ is a cut edge in $G-e$, is $e$ a cut edge in $G-f$?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

It seems not for any general $G$. But if $G$ is 2-connected does the hypothesis hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 2-edge connected graph, $G$,  if $f$ is a cut-edge of $G-e$ that would mean that ($G-e-f$) is disconnected.  Removing of edges is commutative, so $G-f-e$ is also disconnected.  Finally, $G-f$ would have $e$ as a cut-edge since $G-f-e$ is disconnected.

As for the general statement if $G$ were 1 edge-connected, there would be a cut-edge, $f$.  For example, suppose that you have a graph which is a union of two vertex disjoint $K^{50}$'s bridged by a single edge, $f$.  $f$ would be a cut-edge in $G-e$ for any $e$, however $G-f$ wouldn't even be connected, so the definition of "cut-edge" wouldn't even make sense to use in this situation.

However, if $G$ were at least 3 or more edge-connected, there would be no edges $e,f$ satisfying the hypothesis so it is trivially true.